# Default printer via GPO Item Level Targeting in RDS/RemoteApp session

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, remoteapp

Current Setup:

- Server 2008 R2
- GPO uses GPP to create network printer
- Same GPO uses GPP to update printer with item level targeting to set as default.  The item level target is "computer is member of the security group domain\printer1"

I'm using RemoteApp to serve the app.  When the user logs in the GPO runs and adds all 48 network printers (can not change this at all).  I currently have a different GPO to redirect only the user's default printer to the RDS session and it sets it as default.

My goal is to stop redirecting the printer and use only the "native" network printers, but I need to be able to set the default printer via the security group.  User's are unable to set it as default in the RemoteApp session since there is no method to do so in the app.

I am trying to avoid having to add the user to the groups and only want the computer to be in the group.  User's move, but computers/printers typically stay where they are.

Is there a way to accomplish this with item level targeting for the computer in a group in a RemoteApp session?

Answer (score 0):

If you base the target on 'Computer' then it will resolve the RDS server you're logging in to as that 'Computer'.  In order to get it working for client PCs under RDS you'll need to adjust your item level targeting so that it's based on the 'Terminal Session', not the computer.  This can be based on client name, application, or IP ranges if required.

Hope this helps.